# How would I parse "var coords = {'x' : 982, 'y' : 1002 };" in php?

Tags: php

```
var coords = {'x' : 982, 'y' : 1002 };
```

The above code is returned by the API when access via Curl.

I need to parse the x and y values into variables. The two values are also not always the same length. I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

My idea was to use `substr` to cut off the front and back so it's `'x' : 982, 'y' : 1002`, use `explode` to get a var with '`x' : 982` and another with  `'y' : 1002`, then use `explode` again to get  `982` and  `1002`, and finally remove the spaces.

I'm unsure if this is the right path or not. Is this the right way to do it or would you do this another way?

Also, the API I am using is meant for Javascript but I am using PHP, they don't have a PHP
API.

**Edit:**

I have:

```
<?php
$result = "var coords = {'x' : 982, 'y' : 1002 };";
$result = substr($result, 13);
$result = substr($result, 0,strlen ($result) - 1);
$json_obj = json_decode($result);
$x_coord = $json_obj->{'x'};
$Y_coord = $json_obj->{'y'};
echo 'x:' . $x_coord;
echo '<br>';
echo 'y:' . $y_coord;
?>
```

now but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_decode` won't work because although the string is valid JavaScript, it is not valid JSON.

If the string format is exactly as you posted, I'd simply use `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all('/([0-9]+)/', $input, $matches);
list($x, $y) = $matches[0];
```

The reason is simple: while it could be done without regex, less code equals less problems.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Didn't think about doing it that way. super simple and only a few lines!

Answer (score 3):

It's simple, just use the [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) function.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for json_decode. If you try an json_decode the response from the API it will return false. It returns Javascript not json.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json_decode`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). This will produce either an object or an array, depending on the  `assoc` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure of the format of the response then you can use the code below:

```
<?php
$return = "var coords = {'x' : 982, 'y' : 1002 };";
$json = str_replace("'", '"', substr($return, strlen('var coords = '), -1));
$coords = json_decode($json);
var_dump($coords);
```

This relies on the response being just as you posted, it won't work if there are multiple lines or there are single quotes within strings etc.

Running json_decode on `$return` will not work because it is no JSON, it is a javascript (as you said this API is intented for Javascript).

So first we remove the variable assignment and get the result:

```
{'x' : 982, 'y' : 1002 }
```

I believe this is valid JSON depending on what you are using to decode it. In PHP this isn't valid, because the keys/names must be enclosed in double quotes not single quotes.

So with a str_replace on single to double quotes

```
{"x" : 982, "y" : 1002 }
```

No we have valid JSON for PHP. If you json_decode this you will get a stdClass object. And can access the values like so:

```
$coords = json_decode($json);
echo $coords->x;
echo $coords->y;
```

Comment: +1 although your vars are bit confusing `print($coords->x);
print($coords->y);` =P

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$json= '{"x" : 982, "y" : 1002 }';
$obj = json_decode($json);
print($obj->{'x'}); //this will give you 982
print($obj->{'y'}); //this will give you 1002
?>
```

json_decode()

UPDATED, the reason your code did not work is because you must use double quote to cover x and y, sorry i did not read your entire question throughly and basically provided you with merely the tool to parse JSON.  Did not know you have a javascript statement.  I apologize:

```
<?php
$result = "var coords = {'x' : 982, 'y' : 1002 };";
$result = substr($result, 13);
$result = substr($result, 0,strlen ($result) - 1);
$result = preg_replace("/'/", '"', $result);
$json_obj = json_decode($result);
$x_coord = $json_obj->{'x'};
$Y_coord = $json_obj->{'y'};
print('x coord: ' . $json_obj->{'x'}.PHP_EOL);
print('y coord: ' . $json_obj->{'y'});
?>
```